# hostapd_cli chan_switch command

Tags: wifi, wpa, hostapd

I’m using hostapd_cli with the command chan_switch (to change channel by send CSA)

When I used this inputs:

Chan_switch 5 2462

(5 represent the beacon count and 2462 the new frequency channel)

I get a log indication that channel switch started – but never get the log that channel switch is finished

When I look at the sniffer I see that the beacon still contain the CSA message even after 5 beacons

When I used this input:

Chan_switch 1 2462

(1 represent immediately)

I get both logs (started and finished)

Anyone know what is wrong?

(I used hostapd 2.10 and tries to change channel 6 to channel 11)